# Prestashop1.6 theme on prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I have a big problem.

I have installed prestashop 1.7 and I like its administration interface, however, its default theme is not suitable at all for my field of activity compared to that offered by prestashop 1.6.

Here is my question, is it possible to use the prestashop 1.6 default theme on prestashop 1.7.

Really, it would be too cool. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible to make a PrestaShop 1.6 theme work with Prestashop 1.7 and it will never be.

1.7 has changed a lot the template structure and the data passed to the template. The point was to remove logic and calculation from the templates in order to make theme creation much easier.

It was a tough choice for the team but we believe it was the only way to be able to fix so many issues all at once.

Julien

Answer (score 1):

With PrestaShop 1.7 launch, PrestaShop has completely changed the logic and design of many pages in front-end as well as back-end. For example the addition of Symfony in product edit page and modules listing page. PrestaShop has also changed the layout, design and flow of checkout page in the front end.

If you compare the file structure of PrestaShop 1.7 with PrestaShop 1.6 it has many differences, same goes for the structure of a theme in PrestaShop 1.7.

For more details you can check the following links:

http://build.prestashop.com/news/prestashop-1-7-0-0-released/
http://build.prestashop.com/news/prestashop-1-7-faq/